# ¿Se puede usar el mismo número para la WhatsApp Business y la API?

Tags: whatsapp

Acabo de finalizar de hacer un chatbot consumiendo el API de WhatsApp pero quería saber si es posible con el mismo número tener vinculado el api y WhatsApp business?

El chatbot lo realicé en ASP.NET 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para responder a tu pregunta, de acuerdo a la documentación oficial no es posible utilizar el mismo numero simultáneamente para ambas APIs, debes tener un numero particular para integrarte con cada servicio.

Te dejo el link donde se menciona sobre esta limitacion:

https://faq.whatsapp.com/665643701880397/?cms_platform=android

Fijate donde indica:

> Puedes usar las aplicaciones WhatsApp Business y WhatsApp Messenger de forma simultánea, siempre y cuando las cuentas estén asociadas a números de teléfono diferentes. No es posible usar un solo número de teléfono para las dos aplicaciones al mismo tiempo.

Finalmente vas a necesitar un numero de telefono nuevo, que no se haya utilizado antes en la app de business, fijate aqui:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/phone-numbers

Saludos.